# Winter Bash 2016 - why unicorn so small

Tags: discussion, design, winter-bash-2016

I am not sure whether I am the only one noticing this, but if you have a look at the bottom of the [Winter Bash page](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/), there is one massive reindeer on the left and one tiny unicorn to the right.

[image: reindeer]

Sure, you might claim, that the reindeer is in the foreground while as the unicorn is in the background, thus appearing to be smaller in comparison.

So what about this:

[image: head]

Not sure what to look at? Lemme point it out:

[image: compare]

Looks like the unicorn is the same size as a snowflake. If snowflakes the size of me starts falling from sky, I would definitely go into hiding. But that's not point.

Also I could be the only one who thinks the whole Winter Bash page is a bit ... dark. So I added a bright chicken to it.

> Merry Christmas

[image: chicken]

So why is the unicorn so small? I could not but noticing that the unicorn was eventually ridden by a troll at the end of April Fool's day game early this year. Now Stack Exchange has reduced the unicorn to the size of a snowflake under those same snowflakes. Does Stack Exchange subconsciously want to bully the poor little unicorn?

Comment: Hats off to you (pun intended) for asking the hard questions.

Comment: This question is incredible.

Comment: "That's not a massive reindeer - this is a massive reindeer" /crocodiledundee

Comment: Nobody's complained that the chicken is twice the size of the fir tree.

Comment: hahaha that's a well documented question. But I can't find that reindeer

Comment: -1 not enough freehand circles

Answer (score 10):

That "massive reindeer" (bigger than the nearby tree) is not an actual reindeer but a decoration, like this:

[image: holiday lights]

These types of holiday decorations are well-known for having scaling problems.  SE might have gotten its sense of scale from [people like these](http://nczili.com/animated-christmas-light-displays/animated-christmas-light-displays-large-26-christmas-light-displays-amazing-christmas-lights-display-best/) (click the link at your own risk):

[image: giant santa!]

Comment: The website you linked is returning a 502 error

Comment: @Ferrybig thanks for letting me know.  It sounds like that could be a temporary problem, so I'll try to remember to check back tomorrow to see if it's still dead.  Meanwhile, have a [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1064&bih=875&q=overdone+christmas+lights&oq=overdone+christma&gs_l=img.1.3.0l4.3172.5583.0.7484.17.9.0.8.8.0.122.717.8j1.9.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.17.733.-tlqvM4JokI) that produces comparable results. :-)